# EventListener works one time when clicking on button

Tags: typescript, dom, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

im working on my ionic app with google maps js api
my issue is that im trying to call function on clicking on infowindow html button in order to call typescript function , 
the function allow to push to another page , for the first time its works , but when i comback to the first page and clicking second time on the button , it does'nt work , this is bellow the code .
i hope that someone can help me .

```js
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content:"<input type='button' id='clickableItem'value='consulter profile'>"

    });

      
    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', () => {
      //now my elements are ready for dom manipulation
      var clickableItem = document.getElementById('clickableItem');
      clickableItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
      });
    });

  marker.addListener('click', event => {
    infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want open a new page, use a default Ionic NavController, use the push and pop. Ionic is built in Angular 2+ and typescript, avoid when possible using Vanilla JS.

NavController: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/